# Deriving angle from sin or cos

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, circles

How can I derive the value in degrees of an angle starting from either the **cos** or **sin** value?

$$
\cos(t) =  c_{1}
\quad
\text{or}
\quad
\sin(t) = c_{2}
$$

Comment: Use the inverse functions?

Comment: didn't realize there was one :-). Ok found it.. I forgot it from school.. done it too long ago!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please refer to the [trigonometric inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions) functions, especially [arcsine](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseSine.html) and [arccosine](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseCosine.html).

Given that $\cos t = c_1$ and $\sin t = c_2$,

Fundamentally, for a certain range, $\displaystyle t = \arccos(c_1) = \arcsin(c_2)$

Since $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are [many-to-one functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Many-to-One.html), there will correspond multiple values of $x$ that yield a certain $\sin(x)$ or $\cos(x)$ and hence when we say
$$f^{-1}\Big(f(x)\Big) = x $$ 
we mean that $x$ is the smallest positive value which produces a distinct $f(x)$

The inverse trig functions are, on most calculators, written as $\sin^{-1}$ and $\cos^{-1}$ and the functional inverses should  **not** be confused with $\csc x$ or $\sec x$ which are the algebraic inverses.

---

Comment: On many calculators this is also written as $sin^{-1}$ and $cos^{-1}$

Comment: $\sin \pi = 0$ but $\arcsin 0 = 0 \ne \pi$.

Comment: @MartinR, that's true, because the inverse trig on calculators functions restrict their range (the domain of the regular trig functions) to $\pi$ radians with $0$ somewhere in the range. In the case of $\sin^{-1}$, it is $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. In the case of $\cos^{-1}$, it is $[0,\pi]$. This allows the inverse trig functions to become 1-to-1 functions.

Comment: @Dasherman: Noted and I've also added a bit about the algebraic inverses.

Comment: $t = \arccos c_1 = \arcsin c_2$ is wrong, at least if you take the principal values of $\arccos, \arcsin$. You have $t = \pm \arccos c_1 + 2k \pi$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$ and a similar relation holds for the sine. $c_1, c_2$ *together* determine $t$ uniquely modulo $2 \pi$.